# SQL Injection protection in Azure Function App error

Tags: sql, azure, azure-functions, sql-injection

I have Azure Function App functions that I use for API calls from an app to a SQL database. I am trying to use **parameterized queries** to protect the database from **SQL Injection**. I've been able to do it on query statements like SELECT and INSERT, but I'm running into trouble with a DELETE statement. I keep getting a 500 response with an error message of **Must declare the scalar variable "@agencyId".** I am declaring that variable, so I'm not sure why it says that. Does anybody have an idea, or a better way of doing it?

```
const userName1 = process.env["DB_USERNAME"];  
const password1 = process.env["DB_PASSWORD"];  
const server1 = process.env["DB_SERVER"];  
const database1 = process.env["DB_NAME"];  
  
module.exports = async function (context, req) {  
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');  
  
    if (!req.body || !req.body.AGENCY_ID) {  
        context.res = {  
            status: 400,  
            body: "Please provide a valid AGENCY_ID in the request body."  
        };  
        return;  
    }  
  
      const parameters = [  
        { name: 'agencyId', sqlType: sql.Int, value: req.body.AGENCY_ID }  
    ];  
    const query = 'DELETE FROM Agency_Defs WHERE AGENCY_ID = @agencyId;';  

  
    var dbConfig = {  
        server: server1,  
        database: database1,  
        user: userName1,  
        requestTimeout: 600000,  
        password: password1,  
        port: 1433,  
        options: {  
            encrypt: true  
        }  
    };  
  
    try {  
        await sql.connect(dbConfig);  
        const result = await sql.query(query, parameters);  
  
        context.res = {  
            body: result  
        };  
    } catch (error) {  
        context.res = {  
            status: 500,  
            body: error.message  
        };  
    }  
}
```

Comment: pass the parameters from the request boy like this ```{     "AGENCY_ID": 1 }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used this code to delete the Iteams  SQL Server

```java
const  sql = require('mssql');
const  config = {
user:  'sampath125',
password:  'Ra@80muravi',
server:  'sampath234',
database:  'sampath',
};
module.exports = async  function  (context,  req)  {
try  {
await  sql.connect(config);
const  {  agencyId  } = req.body;
if (!agencyId) {
context.res = {
status:  400,
body:  'Please provide the agencyId in the request body.',
};
return;
}
const  query = `DELETE FROM Agency_Defs WHERE AGENCY_ID = @agencyId`;
const  request = new  sql.Request();
request.input('agencyId',  sql.Int,  agencyId);
const  result = await  request.query(query);
await  sql.close();
context.res = {
status:  200,
body:  `Deleted ${result.rowsAffected[0]} records successfully!`,
};
}  catch (err) 
{
context.res = {
status:  500,
body:  err.message,
};
}
};
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**With MSSQL Server:**

[image]

**With Azure SQL Server:**

[image]